# Passing touches to parent view controller after finish of Gesture recognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uitouch

I have added UILongPressGesture on a UIView which is a content of UIScrollView and UIScrollView is in my RootViewController.

When longPress is recognized i want to call the touches began method of my RootViewController.
Means i want get notified when long press is pressed in my RootViewController.

this my hierarchy :
         RootViewController - CustomScrollView - ContentsViews

ContentsViews have longPressGestures , when we get long press gestures i want to call the touches began of RootViewController without lifting the fingere which i have touched screen for long press.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing,
Calling the method of my parent view controller.
You just reference the View Controller.

Like,
**In your gesture recognizer method.**

```
[(RootViewController*)contentsView.superview.superview touches began method];
```

By that you can call

Or

- Create a delegate in contentsView

  Assign your rootviewController to it.

  Modify the name of a touchesbegan to touches began 1

  And call that method of root view controller.

Comment: actually wen i get long press gesture recognized , im removing ContentsViews from scrollview and adding it on rootViewcontroller at same point so that i can move where ever i want on RootViewController,  So how do i get call back that for touches moved in rootview .??

Comment: Think if your touches began method is on contents view then whereever you move your contents view, You can still awake it's touches moved method again.